# Format a Word in php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have retrieve value from mysql database in php, The value is paragraph. I want to format(BOLD) the words which is comes after 'From' and 'To'
Eg : If i get from db is - first name changed: From  abc To xyz. 
Here I want to format (Bold) exactly 'abc' and 'xyz'

edit:

Op wants to define a list of keywords.

He wants to search for those keywords inside a string and add markup to the word following the keyword.

```
$keywords = array('From','To');
$string = 'Going From abc To xyz';
$newString = askedFunction($string, $keywords); 
// add the asked funtionality in this place
// expected result:
echo $newString; // From <b>abc</b> To <b>xyz</b>
```

Comment: Throw some code into your question where you are getting stuck. I reccomend having a look at the Regex functions

Comment: There's no such thing as `BOLD` in PHP. Do you mean the HTML `<b>` or the CSS `font-weight:bold`?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is like in your sample you can do something like this:

```
$marker = array('to', 'from', 'To', 'From');
$text = "first name changed: From abc To xyz";

$words = explode(' ', $text);
$wordsMarkup = array();
$nextBold = false;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $wordsMarkup[] = ($nextBold === true) ? '<b>' . $word . '</b>' : $word;
    $nextBold = false;
    if(in_array($word, $marker)){
        $nextBold = true;
    }
}
echo implode(' ', $wordsMarkup);
exit;
```

You could add some regex to remove non-letter chars before comparing the words to the array containing the "markers". Also this snippet is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$fullString = ' From abc To xyz';
$betweenFromAndTo = $this->getStringBetweenTwoStrings($fullString, 'From', 'To');
$afterTo = explode('To', $fullString)[1];
echo "From <b>$betweenFromAndTo</b> To <b>$afterTo</b>";


function getStringBetweenTwoStrings($string, $fistString, $secondString)
    {
        $stringAfterTheFirstString = explode($fistString, $string);
        if (isset($stringAfterTheFirstString[1])) {
            $stringAfterTheSecondString = explode($secondString, $stringAfterTheFirstString[1]);
            return $stringAfterTheSecondString[0];
        }
        return '';
    }
```